# PHP Array Separation

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a few issues with an array being brought from a database.
The original array once converted looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"lastTimeSave":"1494000000"
    [1] => "rankexpire":"0"
    [2] => "evocity_rank":"g-vip"
    [3] => "evocity_rankexpire":"0"}
)
```

I successfully removed some unuseful characters so my final array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lastTimeSave:1494000000
    [1] => rankexpire:0
    [2] => evocity_rank:g-vip
    [3] => evocity_rankexpire:0
)
```

What I am wanting to do is get everything before the '**:**' and place it into the key of the array, then remove the ':' so it looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    ['lastTimeSave'] => 1494000000
    ['rankexpire'] => 0
    ['evocity_rank'] => g-vip
    ['evocity_rankexpire'] => 0
)
```

I am separating using:

```
$staffarray = str_replace('"', "", $staffarray);
$staffarray = str_replace('{', "", $staffarray);
$staffarray = str_replace('}', "", $staffarray);
```

I have already tried multiple things, including:

```
foreach ($stafftestarray as $key => $value) {
    $substring = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ';'));
    $subsubstring = str_replace($substring, "", $value);
    $value = $subsubstring;
}
```

However nothing seems to change it and the output is not being changed, I would really appreciate any help I can get with this problem as I have searched for countless hours how to fix it to no avail.

Comment: Use explode function in php

Comment: It looks like you're trying to manually parse a JSON string. Why not just use `json_decode()`?

Comment: @AlexHowanskyI completely forgot about JSON, thats a lot easier thanks a lot!

Comment: @JakeButterfield Just take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an exploded json object stored as on array.

Though I'm not sure why your data looks like that (did you explode the string by `,` ?)

This will do what you want:

```
$data = json_decode(implode(',', $yourArray), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the `"` 's and use explode to create a new array based on your old array.

```
$array = array
        (
            0 => "lastTimeSave:1494000000",
            1 => "rankexpire:0",
            2 => "evocity_rank:g-vip",
            3 => "evocity_rankexpire:0"
        );

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $value) 
{
    $item = explode(":", $value);
    $new_array[$item[0]] = $item[1];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Where `print_r($new_array)` will give:

```
Array
(
    [lastTimeSave] => 1494000000
    [rankexpire] => 0
    [evocity_rank] => g-vip
    [evocity_rankexpire] => 0
)
```